# Where is the manifest located?

Tags: android, react-native, expo, android-manifest

I'm trying to publish to the google play store but my app seems to be asking for a ton of permissions that it doesn't need to nor did I specify. After searching, people directed me to edit the permissions in the manifest.xml. The issue is that I don't have one, nor do I have an "app\src\main" folder. This is what my folders look like:

[image: What my folders look like]

I initialized my project using `expo init [app name]`

I'm using Visual studio code, Expo, react native, and javascript.

Answer (score 4):

Add `permissions: []` in app.json (https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/config/app/#permissions). It will still add some permissions that are required for expo to work.

AndroidManifest.xml you mentioned exists in expo project only in bare projects, you would need to eject to have direct access to this file. In managed workflow you have only javascript, all parts of the native android or ios projects like e.g. AndroidManifest.xml are generated on expo servers based on app.json.

Comment: in addition to the above correct information that Wojciech provided, you might find this useful: https://docs.expo.io/distribution/app-stores/#android-permissions

Comment: https://docs.expo.dev/guides/permissions/#android